# How to remove delay when changing ViewController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I experience some delay when my app is moving between `ViewControllers`. I wonder how I can solve that? The problem occurs when I check user signed in to firebase. I post code below:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Check if user is signed in!!

    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {

        // Move to MapController
        print("USER: SIGNED IN")
        self.moveToMain()

    } else {

        //User Not logged in
        print("USER: NOT SIGNED IN")
    }
}
```

So, ofc I can see that there's a problem when this code fires AFTER the `view.didLoad()`. And this is part of the problem, I wanna do this BEFORE `view.didLoad()` or somehow override this function IF the user is signed in.

At the moment there is very bad UI since user gets to login-page and after .5 sec moves into main. Any suggestions folks?

P.S. I'm newbie, would appreciate if you could also explain how I can avoid this delay regardless the transition is fired inside `view.didLoad` or in any function/buttonAction.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to have a class, let's name it as `RootViewController`. In this controller, you will load every setup from the server, and also here you will validate the token or the authentication of the user (i.e. if user is logged in or not).

And then the `RootViewController` will determine what controller (Home? Authentication screen?) will be presented OR will replace the `UIWindow` in the App Delegate. Whatever you wanna do with moving to another screen, at lease you get the flow here.

You can make the `RootViewController`'s screen design to be equal to the `LaunchScreen` so that the user will feel like he's still in the launch screen and not in some weird random screen.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can I set the delay on that RootController if so? To act as launchscreen? I'm not really sure. Do you mean that I should REPLACE the built-in launchScreen or create RootController with exactly the same design?

Comment: The problem is following: LaunchScreen -> LoginController -> (HERE GOES DELAY) -> MainController

Comment: You don't need to worry about such delay. What I was suggesting is you to setup `RootController` that will be displayed after the `LaunchScreen`, but the user will still feel that he's in the launch screen, so it won't be noticed that it's actually a new screen that does some setup stuff. If there's a delay, so be it, it could be Firebase or anything, as long as it does not affect UX much. If you want, you can have an `ActivityLoader` or a HUD.

Comment: Ok great, I try it out and see what I think about it! Thanks.

Comment: Okay sure. You're welcome. And welcome to Stackoverflow. You might want to consider selecting an answer in every question of yours if it actually answers your question. :D You can select other answer if there's a better one.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was a brilliant solution for this problem I were facing. Now it looks like a beautiful flower while launching! :D

Comment: Awesome. I'm glad I was able to help.